# Prevent an input box from being added if it doesn't contain data (no user keypress)

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the question says, how can I prevent an `input box` from being added if it doesn't contain data (= user didn't press any key).

Here's my code so far:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> //<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
    $(function(){
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

        $('#addScnt').live('click', function(){
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value"/></label><a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
        });

        $('#remScnt').live('click', function() {
            if (i > 2) {
                $(this).parents('p').remove();
                i--;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
}); //]]>  
</script>

<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>
```

The goal is that you can't add another input box if

```
<input type="text"id="p_scnt">
```

is empty.
How can I do that?

```
<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts">
            <input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark 'accepted answer' to the most useful post..:)

Comment: Will you elaborate in which condition you don't want to add text box ? I mean when immediate above text box is empty

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking that the last `input` element of the container to which the elements are appended is not empty (that it has an entered value) and, if there is a value add a new `input`, if not, then do nothing.

This is demonstrated below:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    var target = $('#container'),
        newLabel = $('<label />'),
        newInput = $('<input />').appendTo(newLabel);
    if (target.find('input').last().val() !== '') {
        newLabel.appendTo(target)
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TCbn9/).

This does require grouping the `input` elements together in a common container, of course (in order to find the last element).

The code you posted implies that you add multiple elements with the same `id`, which is invalid HTML and will cause problems with JavaScript (which will only return the *first* element it finds with a given `id`).

Answer (score 0):

Modified your click function like this :

```
$('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
    if($("#p_scents input").last().val() != ""){
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    }
});
```

This should work. It check wether the last input field in your 'p_scents' div is empty or not. If it is not empty, the script will add a new input.

Answer (score 0):

I update your jsfiddle and check here http://jsfiddle.net/QfXpE/1/

first, use class for inputs instead of ids.

And use jquery .on click event instead of .live, coz live is deprecated http://api.jquery.com/live/

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = 1;

    $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
        if($('input.p_scnt_'+(i-1)).val() != ''){
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" class="p_scnt_'+i+'" size="20" name="p_scnt_'+i+'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
        }
        else{
            alert('Enter some data first!');
            $('input.p_scnt_'+(i-1)).focus();
        }
    });

    $('#remScnt').on('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
 });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    $('#addScnt').on('click', function () {
        if($('input:last').val()!=''){
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts_' + $('p').length + '"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + $('p').length + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);        
    }else{
        alert('Input must have a value...');
    }
    });
    $('#remScnt').live('click',function () {        
        $(this).parent('p').remove();
    });
});
</script>

<h2><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts">
            <input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
```

**If you are using latest jQuery then you have to use 'on' instead of 'live'.**

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/yCXQA/2/)